# My jquery ajax code refresh the page without reason

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I have simple ajax-jquery/html/php code, but I get the problem when I click on button to add data, then page just refresh and nothing happend, also I cant see what is the problem becouse then my `success, error` into ajax dont work becouse page was refreshed...

Here I have jquery / ajax code:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
$("#addCom").click(function() {
    var tabela = 'parcele';
        $.ajax({
            url: "insertKom.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { ajdi:ajdi, tabela:tabela,zakoga:$("#zakoga").val(),beleska:$("#beleska").val(),podsetnik:$("#podsetnik").val()},
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);  
            },
            error:function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
            }
        });

});
 });
```

also HTML:

```
 <div class="jumbotron">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>


<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="zakoga">Odnosi se na:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="zakoga" name="zakoga" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="beleska">Beleska - komentar</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="beleska" name="beleska"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="podsetnik">Podsetnik za dan:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
<div class="input-append date" id="podsetnik" data-date="2014-05-05" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
  <input class="span2 form-control" size="16" type="text" value="">
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>    
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="addCom"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="addCom" name="addCom" class="btn btn-primary">Dodaj belesku</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>

    </div>
```

and PHP PDO - insert file:

```
 try {        
                $STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO zalihe (tabela, id_utabeli, datum, podsetnik, naslov, komentar, user_id) VALUES (:2,:1,:6,:3,:4,:5,:7)");

                $STH->bindParam(':1', $_POST['ajdi']);
                $STH->bindParam(':2', $_POST['tabela']);
                $STH->bindParam(':3', $_POST['podsetnik']);
                $STH->bindParam(':4', $_POST['zakoga']);
                $STH->bindParam(':5', $_POST['beleska']);
                $STH->bindParam(':6', now());
                $STH->bindParam(':7', $user_id);

                $STH->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            echo "<p>Data submitted successfully</p>";
```

But when I click on button with ID=addCom then page just refresh and nothing add to database. What can be the reason?

Comment: Usually this is caused because your form is being submitted and the form submission causes the page reload, but I don't see why that would be happening in your HTML.

Comment: My guess is that clicking the button will also submit the form, which will just reload the page. Try preventing the submit event. (`.click*(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ... })`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action. Try:

```
 $("#addCom").click(function(evt) {
     evt.preventDefault();
     ....
```

[official docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: @gmaestro, try using `<button type="button" id="addCom" name="addCom" class="btn btn-primary">`

Answer (score 1):

try this , add event.preventDefault();

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#addCom").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    var tabela = 'parcele';
        $.ajax({
            url: "insertKom.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { ajdi:ajdi, tabela:tabela,zakoga:$("#zakoga").val(),beleska:$("#beleska").val(),podsetnik:$("#podsetnik").val()},
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);  
            },
            error:function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
            }
        });

});
 });
```

Comment: try to change <button id="addCom" name="addCom" >Dodaj belesku</button> to <span id="addCom" name="addCom">Dodaj belesku<span>

Answer (score 1):

You need preventDefault to stop the form from submitting.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#addCom").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //functions
 });
});
```

Comment: can I prevent this into html?