# Why is webpage refreshing when I click on a button and not when call the function of the button in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I call my function directly in the javascript console of my browser, it's doesn't refresh my webpage as intended but if I do it with a button, it does :

I have already tried this [My jquery ajax code refresh the page without reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851075/my-jquery-ajax-code-refresh-the-page-without-reason) but it does not seem to work for me

```
$('<button>')
            .attr('onclick',"nextQuestion()")
            .attr('class', "btn btn-success")
            .html('Suivant')
```

Comment: Maybe include the function?

Comment: Please show more of your HTML (e. g. the `button` is not by any chance a submit button, right?) and what your `nextQuestion` function does.

Comment: Thank you , I will put the html online in a few minuts ,it's not a submit button .

Comment: Make sure to include the function in the question itself…

Comment: Is the button inside of a form? is it the only button in the form? does it have a type attribute?

Comment: To reproduce the issue:

go here: http://goldiman3.alwaysdata.net/2JSQUiMarche/www/
-Click on Blue button
-Select only one anwser and click on the green button
-The webpage should refresh

-Open you js console
-Click on Blue button
-Select one anwser  and type in your js console nextQuestion()
-Should not refresh

Comment: @goldiman I cannot reproduce this. And the code itself still isn’t in the question itself (the code should only include the relevant parts).

Comment: @Xufox At which step are you stuck reproducing it? The function is kinda big, is this not going to be confusing?

Comment: @goldiman When I click on the green button it doesn’t refresh. Again, only include the most relevant part.

Comment: Just tried with Internet Explorer and it's work as intented, this seems to be an issue with chrome, do you have google chrome?

Comment: I tried Google Chrome, could not reproduce. Clicking the button has the same effect as executing the function through the console.

Comment: Can you try doing it several times, sometime it does it on the second/third try.

Comment: Okay, I reproduced it. That is weird.

Comment: Good to know that i'm not fully crazy, any suggestion ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `type` for a button is `submit` so when you click a button in a form it will submit the form by default.

This is what is causing your page refresh.

You can prevent this by setting `type=button`

```
$('<button>', {type: 'button'})
        .attr('onclick',"nextQuestion()")
        .attr('class', "btn btn-success")
        .html('Suivant')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( 'button' ).on('click' , nextQuestion).attr('class', "btn btn-success").html('Suivant') ;
```

I suggest that you use an ID on the button, and replace `button, with`#ButtonID`.

Comment: I tried to do this but it doesn't seem to work but anyway I will had an id to this button :)